# e format in printf() and precision modifiers

Tags: c, printf, format-specifiers

Could you explain me why

```
printf("%2.2e", 1201.0);
```

gives a result `1.20e+03` and not just `12.01e2`?

My way of thinking: default number is 1201.0, specifier tells are that there should be 2 numbers after the digit.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#Normalized_notation):

> In normalized scientific notation, the exponent b is chosen so that the absolute value of a remains at least one but less than ten (1 ≤ |a| < 10). Thus 350 is written as 3.5×10<sup>2</sup>. This form allows easy comparison of numbers, as the exponent b gives the number's order of magnitude. In normalized notation, the exponent b is negative for a number with absolute value between 0 and 1 (e.g. 0.5 is written as 5×10<sup>−1</sup>). The 10 and exponent are often omitted when the exponent is 0.
>
> Normalized scientific form is the typical form of expression of large numbers in many fields, unless an unnormalised form, such as engineering notation, is desired. Normalized scientific notation is often called exponential notation—although the latter term is more general and also applies when a is not restricted to the range 1 to 10 (as in engineering notation for instance) and to bases other than 10 (as in 3.15× 2<sup>20</sup>).

Answer (score 2):

The `%e` format uses scientific notation, i.e. one digit before the decimal separator and an exponent for scaling. You can't set the digits *before* the decimal separator using this format.

Answer (score 2):

The first `2` in `"%2.2e"` is the *minimum* character width to print.  `1.20e+03` is 8 characters which is more than 2.

`e` directs that the number is printed: (sign), 1 digit, `'.'`, followed by some digits and an exponent.

The 2nd `2` in `"%2.2e"` is the number of digits after the decimal point to print.  6 is used if this 2nd value is not provided.

Answer (score 1):

This is just how the scientific notation is defined. The result you expect is a very weird notation. I don't think you can get it with printf.

The number before the dot in the format specifier defines the minimum width of the resulting sub-string. Try `%20.2e` to see what that means.