# Two different result values, I've been researching for days and still can't understand

Tags: c

Below is the code：

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    float toobig = 3.4E38 * 100.0f;
    float toosmall = (0.1234E-10) / 10;
    printf("%f\n", toobig);
    printf("%e\n", toosmall);
    return 0;
}
```

The result of running after compilation is:

```
PS D:\c\test1> .\a
1.#INF00
1.234000e-012
```

But the value of `toosmall` on the book is:

```
0.0123E-10
```

I have been researching this problem for a few days, but I still can't understand the result of the compiler running: `1.234000e-012`, why is it different from the book?

Comment: "on the book" - What book?

Comment: Are `0.0123E-10` and `1.234000e-012` really that different? Perhaps you should brush up on exponential notation.

Comment: What compiler and standard library are you and "the book" using? It's a bit strange that the format specifier was `%e` and the result supposedly contains a capital E.

Comment: @MOehm perhaps the representation is important for the OP.

Comment: All implemantations I tried show `1.234000e-012` which is what is expected. Maybe it's time to burn your book. Which book BTW?

Comment: @GuillaumePetitjean: Sure, could be, but the title says "values", not "representation" or "rounding". Perhaps the `0.0123E-10` are not the exact output, but just a value given in the book. As is. we can't know. Perhaps OP can clarify.

Answer (score 2):

The program behaves almost as expected according to the C Standard:

`toolarge` is indeed beyond the range of the `float` type on your system. Note that the expression `3.4E38 * 100.0f` is evaluated using `double` arithmetics because `3.4E38` is a `double` constant.

The value of `toosmall` is a the closest approximation of `0.01234E-10` that fits in a `float`, converting it with `%e` produces a decimal representation with one non-zero digit before the `.`, 6 decimals and an exponent that should be at least 2 digits and at most as many are needed to represent the exponent, using a small case `e`. The expected output is **`1.234000e-12`**.

The book's `0.0123E-10` is completely incorrect, not even using the right exponent indicator. There are probably many more errors in this book.

Your C library is incorrect too because there should be just 2 digits in the exponent. Judging from the shell prompt, you probably use Turbo-C, which is a very old compiler that does not conform to the C Standard.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your "book" is acting weird. See [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29520231/e-format-in-printf-and-precision-modifiers).

What you see on your machine is the correct behaviour.

By the way I don't understand the name of the variable `toosmall`. in usual 3é bits float representation you can go down to `e-38` approcimatively